# How to center a inner circle using css

Tags: html, css

```css
div.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
span.parent{
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-radius:50%;
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:10px;
}

span.child{
  background:green;
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  left:10%;
  top:10%;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>some info goes here</p>
  <span class="parent"><span class="child"></span></span>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a filled circle with border, but getting not the fill properly centered. how to fix this?

Comment: Try `absolute` instead of `relative` in the `child` class, and put it before `left`

Comment: why someone do downvote to all answers ..?

Comment: All answers are correct and giving the desired result. Then why someone is giving downvote to all answers. Atleast run the snippet first before giving vote.

Comment: @Jay , I think, easy question that not means that give downvote because answer is correct. If someone didn't give upvote to correct answer then someone has no right to give downvote.

Comment: @Jay hmm but that is not good.

Comment: Luckily downvoting someone's answer also gives the downvoter a loss of reputation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do this is by using Flexbox.

If you add the following to your parent:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

And remove the relative positioning from the child element, the child element will be centered inside the parent.

```css
div.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
span.parent{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-radius:50%;
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:10px;
}

span.child{
  background:green;
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>some info goes here</p>
  <span class="parent"><span class="child"></span></span>
</div>
```

**Edit:** If you encounter a problem with flexbox circles being squashed on smaller resolutions, try using `min-height` and `min-width`, and using `margin: auto` for centering instead of `display: flex`.

Comment: only problem is, when the page get resize the circle shape is missing. and getting oval shape, is there any way to fix that still the page on resize?

Comment: Correct, try using `min-width` and `min-height` instead of `width` and `height`. I have encountered this problem before but I can't recall the fix other than removing the flexbox and using `margin: auto` for centering

Answer (score 0):

Give `left:0;` to `span.child` class.

```css
div.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
span.parent{
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-radius:50%;
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:10px;
}

span.child{
  background:green;
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  left:0;
  top:10%;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>some info goes here</p>
  <span class="parent"><span class="child"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: works. but what is the login behind? Is this technically correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the position to `position:absolute` in place of `position:relative` for child span `span.child`.

```css
div.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
span.parent{
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-radius:50%;
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:10px;
}

span.child{
  background:green;
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  left:10%;
  top:10%;
  align:center;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>some info goes here</p>
  <span class="parent"><span class="child"></span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `position: absolute` in `child` instead to center it

```
span.child{
  background:green;
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I also changed the value of `left` and `top`, and added `transform:translate()` to make sure it is always centered regardless of browser size

```css
div.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

span.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 10px;
}

span.child {
  background: green;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>some info goes here</p>
  <span class="parent"><span class="child"></span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Changed the `position:relative` to `position:absolute` of **span.child**

```css
div.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
span.parent{
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-radius:50%;
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:10px;
}

span.child{
  background:green;
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  left:10%;
  top:10%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>some info goes here</p>
  <span class="parent"><span class="child"></span></span>
</div>
```